# Update Previous Row Based on Current Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    CustomerKey Person_Number Start_Date    End_Date
        1       250644    2017-01-01    4712-12-12
        2       250644    2017-01-10    4712-12-12
        3       250644    2017-01-15    4712-12-12
```

I required SQL Query where End date to be updated next Start_Date-1 nd last end should be 4712-12-12.

```
   CustomerKey  Person_Number Start_Date    End_Date
        1       250644      2017-01-01    2017-01-09
        2       250644      2017-01-10    2017-01-14
        3       250644      2017-01-15    4712-12-12
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `lag()`.  This requires a self-join in the `update`:

```
update t
    set end_date = next_start_date - interval '1 day'
    from (select t.*,
                 lead(start_date) over (partition by person_number order by start_date) as next_start_date
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.customerkey = t.customerkey and
          tt.next_start_date is not null;
```

Although the above basically works with SQL Server (except for the date arithmetic), the question was originally tagged Postgres.  The better SQL Server solution is:

```
update tt
    set end_date = dateadd(day, -1, next_start_date)
    from (select t.*,
                 lead(start_date) over (partition by person_number order by start_date) as next_start_date
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.next_start_date is not null;
```

A self-join is not necessary in SQL Server.

Comment: @at9063, as the one posed the question, you can accept a correct answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Update previous row based on current value:

```
update t1
set t1.End_Date = dateadd(day, -1, t2.Start_Date)
from tbl t1
inner join tbl t2 on t1.CustomerKey = (t2.CustomerKey - 1)
```

Comment: This solution of course is going to **fail** if there's ever a gap in the "CustomerKey" - if you have customers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9 - then trying to update no. 9 or no. 5 will **fail** because the previous customer isn't the one with a "CustomerKey" value of "-1"  ......